# Mounting windows share to Rasbian Jessie

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi2

I have read a lot of posts on this but nothing i try seems to work.

I have a windows 10 machine which has a share on it. The share does not require a username or password to access. 
I can ping the machine from the pi fine. The share has permission "everyone" full access

i have tried cifs with no luck, but if i type this into a terminal window

`sudo mount //192.168.1.153/Mybook /mnt/Media`

It asks me for my password. I just hit enter with no password and it mounts. 
I then umount /mnt/Media

I then try to add to fstab

`//192.168.1.153/Mybook /mnt/Media cifs guest,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

I have tried writing the above many different ways this is just the last way i have tried.

I then exit and try to do

`sudo mount -a and nothing happens it just hangs.`

I do a reboot and then check df -h and its not there.

I am out of ideas on what to try. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally gave up and just added a windows password to my share.